# Cannot open app from in-app browser?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I am building a `cordova` app. I am using `IntentFilter` so that when I click on a link the in-app browser should close it and open the app homepage. My code is working fine with previous version of `Phonegap`, but not working with the latest version. Here is my `IntentFilter` looks like :

```html
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application/activity" mode="add">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
       <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="fooddabba.mobile.app" android:pathPattern=".*"/>
    </intent-filter>       
</gap:config-file>
```